# Multiple Threads in Java for ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading

I made a two thread one is get Data and another is save Data.
**My problem is it is not handled in the process of storing the data read from Thread1.**

I want to extract 1,000,000 elements and create them as file. The element size is so big, So i divide a elements size by 100,000. And then, the loop will run a 10 time. One thread reads a data from other server by 100,000. Another thread takes the data from the first thread and writes it to a file.

My Original scenario is below:

First thread read a total key, value size.
It will be 100,000 ~ 1,000,000. I would assume that i would process 1,000,000 data.Then Count sets 1,000,000. First Thread divide by 100,000 and read a data from server by 100,000. And then, First Thread calls a setData(Key,Value map).
It will loop 10 times.

Second Thread will loop 10 time. first, get a data by calling getMap() method. And It calls writeSeq(hashmap) method. It writes a data to writer stream. It is not yet flush. There is a problem here. It successfully gets a data size by calling getMap(). But, writeSeq method can not process all of size of value. When i gets a size of 100,000, it process as random. It will be 100, 1500, 0, 8203 ...

First Thread is below:

```
public void run() {
        getValueCount(); //initialize value.

        while (this.jobFlag) {
            getSortedMap(this.count); //count starts the number of all elements size.
//For example, Total size is 1,000,000. Then count will sets a 1,000,000 and it is decreased as 100,000.
// Also setMap() is called in this method.
            if (!jobFlag) //If all processing is done, jobFlag is set as false.
                break;
        }

        resetValue();
    }
```

Second Thread is below:

```
public void run() {
        setWriter(); //Writer Stream creates;

        double count  = 10; //the number of loop. 

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> hash = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
            hash = share.getMap();
            writeSeq(hash);
        }

        closeWriter(); //close Writer stream
    }
```

This is shared source:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ShareData {

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map;

    public synchronized ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getMap(){
        if (this.map == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> hashmap = map;

        this.map = null;

        return hashmap;
    }

    public synchronized void setMap(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> KV) {
        if (this.map != null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        this.map = KV;
        notify();
    }

}
```

After that, second thread which save a data is stared. **The size of KV is fine, but all values are not processed when foreach is proecessed.** Also, each time i create a file, the size is different. Is it problem of synchronized?

```
public synchronized void writeSeq(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> KV) {

        AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);
        System.out.println(KV.size()); //ex) 65300
        redisKV.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(
                entry -> { 
                    try {
                        a.incrementAndGet();
                        writer.append(new Text(entry.getKey()), new Text(entry.getValue()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        System.out.println(a.get()); //ex) 1300
        i = 0;
        notify();

    }
```

Comment: you might need two simple patterns in order to implement that. i) Scatter ii) Producer - Consumer , so you are not blocking anything and not streching the cpu/mem too much. Also , your numbers are not quite correct (10 times of 100.000), you ll need to perform a statistical test to conclude to the best values and your code does not really allowing you to do so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The size of KV is fine, but all values are not processed when foreach is processed. Also, each time i create a file, the size is different. Is it problem of synchronized?

Unclear.  I can see a small issue but it is not likely to cause the problem you describe.

- The `if (map == null) wait();` code should be a `while` loop.
- The `if (map != null) wait();` code should be a `while` loop.

The issue is that if one thread gets a spurious notify, it may proceed with `map` in the wrong state.  You need to retry the test.  (If you read the javadoc for `Object`, you will see an example that *correctly* implements a condition variable.)

Apart from that, the root cause of your problem does not appear to be in the code that you have shown us.

---

However, if I was to take a guess, my guess would be that one thread is adding or removing entries in the `ConcurrentHashMap` while the second thread is processing it<sup>1</sup>.  The `getMap` / `setMap` methods you have shown us have to be *used* appropriately (i.e. called at appropriate points with appropriate arguments) to avoid the two threads interfering with each other.  You haven't shown us *that* code.

So, if my guess is correct, your problem is a logic error rather than a low level synchronization problem.  But if you need a better answer you will need to write and post a proper MCVE.

---

<sup>1 - A ConcurrentHashMap's iterators are *weakly consistent*.  This means that if you update the map while iterating, you may miss entries in the iteration, or possibly see them more than once.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change a way of your. But it is not working also.
I will add a another source too.

Comment: *"Thanks, I tried to change a way of your. But it is not working also."* - I did say that I thought it wasn't your real problem.  *"I will add a another source too."* - A proper MCVE please.  Something I can copy and paste into a file, compile, run and see the problem.  (I will be busy for the next 8 hours, so you have plenty of time to write it :-) )

Comment: I figured out issue. Thanks all!
My issue was a logic problem, and could avoid a dead lock by your ways.

Answer (score 2):

`i++;` is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). You will get a lower count than there are updates. Use `AtomicInteger` And its `incrementAndGet()` method instead.

Comment: i value is just checking how many a data read. That is not problem. 
I get the same 1,000,000 when I create a file, but the file size is different every time I create it.

Comment: I also change a int to AtomicInteger, But It also not same with first KV size.

Answer (score 2):

better way is using BlockingQueue,  one thread put the queue, another thread take from the queue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried also BlockingQueue. But it also same problem.